# __builtin_object_size always returns -1

Tags: c, gcc, memory-management, sizeof

I understood, that `__builtin_object_size` should give information about the size of an object, if it can be determined at compile time or the relevant call to `malloc` uses the attribute `alloc_size`. I think I compiled the code ok with gcc 9.3 on ubuntu 20.04 with

```
gcc -g -std=gnu11 -Wall -O2 compstrcpyos.c -o compstrcpyos.exe -lbsd
```

The code should at least find out in `doit` the size, but it doesn't. I get -1 as result.

```
void doit(char *buf1, char *buf2, const char *src) {
  printf("bos1=%zd, bos2=%zd\n",
       __builtin_object_size(buf1, 0),
       __builtin_object_size(buf2, 0));
  strlcpy(buf1, src, __builtin_object_size(buf1, 0));
  strlcpy(buf2, src, __builtin_object_size(buf2, 0));
  for (size_t i=0; i < strlen(buf1); ++i) {
    buf1[i] = tolower(src[i]);
  }  
  for (size_t i=0; i < strlen(buf2); ++i) {
    buf2[i] = tolower(src[i]);
  }  
}

void *malloc(size_t s) __attribute__((alloc_size (1)));

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2) { return -1; }
  char buf1[20];
  char *buf2 = malloc(20);
  printf("bos1=%zd, bos2=%zd\n",
         __builtin_object_size(buf1, 0),
         __builtin_object_size(buf2, 0));
  doit(buf1, buf2, argv[1]);
  printf("%s\n%s\n", buf1, buf2);
}
```

Running the code gives.

```
$ ./compstrcpyos.exe ABCDefghijklmnopq
bos1=20, bos2=20
bos1=-1, bos2=-1
abcdefghijklmnopq
abcdefghijklmnopq
```

I tried to add the option `-fsanitize=object-size`, I tried with the constants 1, 2 and 3 instead 0 in the call to `__builtin_object_size`, but never got 20 in `doit`. What do I need to do get 20, 20 on the second line (that is in `doit`) as well.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: It seems like the classic 'pass an array' problem.  In C, an array name is just a pointer to the bottom element, nothing more.  A pointer in a 64 bit compile is 8 bytes.  In a local bit of code, sizeof can tell you the local array size, but in a called routine, all you get is a pointer to the bottom element.  They invented the null character term char[] and null pointer term array of pointers for this!  You can pass the size, know the size, define a global or MACRO to tell you the size, or move to C++ array and vector classes, which internally store and adjust their size and capacity.

Comment: @DavidG.Pickett Thanks, but I was experimenting with `__builtin_object_size` which should be able to determine a little bit more. I think this would be nice for legacy code as test environment, where you cannot change the signature to pass the size through all calls. My understanding was that the builtin/extension is meant for this. Otherwise there is no point for this extension, as there is sizeof if it is in the definition scope. And yeah, everybody should prefer C++ or even better rust, but for some checks for legacy code with rigid interfaces this extension would be nice...

Comment: I believe that `sizeof` is less capable here, `sizeof` will work on `buf1` the array but not a pointer to a `malloc`d buffer. It seems that `__builtin_object_size` is trying to do something a little more holistic for the specific purpose of bounds checking and preventing overflows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are over-estimating the reach of the compiler:

> I understood, that `__builtin_object_size` should give information about the size of an object, if it can be determined at compile time

Up to here, fine.

> or the relevant call to malloc uses the attribute `alloc_size`.

But this is not a disjunction ("or"). The compiler can only know what is known at compile time. So there is no alternative to being able to determine the size at compile-time. Now, if an object is allocated dynamically, the compiler may still be able to determine its size, provided that:

- It is allocated by a function which the compiler recognises as a dynamic allocation function, and
- The compiler can deduce from the argument(s) to the dynamic allocation function what the size of the allocated object is, and
- The compiler can determine the values of those argument(s).

For the first two points, the compiler relies on the `alloc_size` attribute. If the allocation function is not marked with this attribute, the compiler cannot determine the size of the object. So it's a conjunction ("and"). But even that is not sufficient; the compiler also needs to be able to determine the value of the arguments used when the object was allocated.

For that to work through a function call, the function call basically must be inlined. Static functions will normally be inlined if they are only called in one place. (They may be inlined elsewhere, but a large function is unlikely to be inlined if it is called -- or potentially called -- from more than one call site.)

In short, you would have been more accurate had you said:

> `__builtin_object_size` should give information about the size of an object, if it can be determined at compile time, ***which requires*** the relevant call to `malloc` to have the attribute `alloc_size` *and that its arguments can be determined at compile time*.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Indeed it appears I was expecting too much from the compiler/runtime. It seems I wanted a memory tracing functionality. I'll accept that answer. And thanks to ben-zotto, who suggested `static`, which worked for the example at hand.

Answer (score 3):

Indirecting through the function call erases the ability of the compiler to feel confident in determining the sizes. In theory, that function could be called by other callers, including ones outside the translation unit (file). If you add a `static` qualifier to the `doit` function declaration that would signal that there are never external callers, and it's then possible (in this particular example) to make a definitive compile-time determination.

For what it's worth, `__builtin_object_size` is not the idiomatic way of saying "how big is this thing". It appears intended to be used in ways [like the example](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Object-Size-Checking.html) here in super defensive coding inside one scope.

The idiomatic way of passing a buffer with an explicit size to a function is to pass the buffer and also the size of it as separate arguments (or as part of a context struct or whatnot)

Comment: thanks, with `static` added to the function `doit` I get 20, 20 as expected. However, in the long run I was hoping that `__builtin_object_size` at least with the attributes does something clever and works cross compilation unit boundaries.

If there is no answer pointing to a more sensible use of `__builtin_object_size` I will accept the answer and discard the usage of `__builtin_object_size` as if it requires a `static` it does not provide much improvement over `sizeof`...

Comment: @pba: Ah, interesting. Thanks for the update (edited the answer to reflect it). And I, too, am curious if others have more useful working knowledge.

Comment: The nice thing of `__builtin_object_size` compared to `sizeof` is that it would allow to know dynamically if the size of a pointed value is known at compile time or not (for being used in macros for example, without erroring), but this doesn't seem to work reliably either.